# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Stuck at Detecting File Systems

Tags: 20.04

I followed the following steps:

-Formatted my SD drive using SD formatter. https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter/

- Downloaded Ubuntu from the website and Flashed the ISO file onto my USB drive using Rufus
  https://rufus.ie/en/
- I then restarted my laptop and chose to boot from USB.
- Followed installation instructions, and chose "something else" for installing type.
- I have about 50000 MB of free space, and chose to use 45000 MB for /,
  and I used the rest for swap space.

-When I click install now it stops at the loading screen and never finished Detecting File system ...

I have read the following answers and it has not solved my problem:

https://itsfoss.community/t/ubuntu-20-04-installation-with-usb-in-dual-boot-gets-stuck-at-detecting-file-systems/4751

Comment: Did you verify the integrity of the ISO before flashing? When you say you have free space, is this **unpartitioned free space** or something else?  Are there any other operating systems already installed or any data partitions you need to keep?  If no, you should format the disk (as GPT) prior to starting the installation

Comment: @Nmath I have Windows 10 installed on a Thinkpad. ON Windows 10 I freed up some space from my C drive. I wanted to dual boot windows 10 along with Ubuntu.

Comment: Free space on what Windows calls "C" is not space that is usable by Ubuntu.  You need **unpartitioned free space**. I would advise against using the "something else" option if you are trying to set up dual boot config and you are not proficient and experienced in installing Ubuntu.  You also don't need a swap partition. Ubuntu will create a swap file. Free up enough unpartitioned free space to install Ubuntu and the installer will provide you a guided "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows" option to make your life easier.

Comment: @Nmath How would I free up unpartitioned free space on Windows 10? Would I do it through the disk manager? Thank you for the help.

Comment: You will need to consult with Windows documentation/help to shrink your Windows partition.  Try searching/asking on Super User

Comment: As above but yes, you can do it with Disk Manager. Right-click the partition and the rest should be self-explanatory.